# java EE Cant instantiate class

Tags: java, jsf, locale

Привет всем! Я сейчас изучаю java ee, решил написать свою онлайн библиотеку.
Использую glassfish and jsf.
Сделал интернационализацию и при загрузке главной страницы index.xhtml выбивает следующую ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.javabegin.training.web.beans.LocaleChanger.<init>(LocaleChanger.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:186)
```

на странице `index.xhtml` вставляю `<ui:include src="/templates/locales.xhtml"/>`

вот файл `locales.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition>
     <div class="locales">
          <h:form>
             <h:commandLink action="#{localeChanger.changeLocale('en')}">
                 <h:graphicImage library="images" name="eng.png" title="#{msg.english}"/>
             </h:commandLink>
             <h:commandLink action = "#{localeChanger.changeLocale('ru')}">
                 <h:graphicImage library="images" name="rus.png" title="#{msg.russian}"/>
             </h:commandLink>
          </h:form>
     </div>
</ui:composition>
```

и сам класс:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class LocaleChanger implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Locale currentLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();

    public LocaleChanger() {
    }

    public void changeLocale(String localeCode) {
        currentLocale = new Locale(localeCode);
    }

    public Locale getCurrentLocale() {
        return currentLocale;
    }

}
```

не понимаю в чем может быть причина этой ошибки, если можете подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

NPE может произойти в трёх случаях:

1. Его кинули с помощью throw
2. Кто-то кинул null с помощью throw
3. Кто-то пытается обратиться по null-ссылке

В данном случае, судя по трейсу у нас как раз 3-й вариант.

По всей видимости у вас допущена ошибка в этой строке:

```
 Locale currentLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
```

Один из методов в этой строке возвращает null. Скорее всего `getCurrentInstance()`

Comment: спасибо за ответ, а какая причина может быть в том, что getCurrentInstance () выбрасывает java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @BohdanBodnar так я же написал NPE возвращает не getCurrentInstance (), он скорее всего возвращает null, а бросает NPE уже getViewRoot(), по тому, что обращение происходит к null.

Answer (score 2):

Создание бинов производится контейнером во время первого обращения к ним из программы, отложенным образом. Незамедлительное, раннее создание бина возможно только для аннотации `@ApplicationScoped`, о чем имеется явное указание в описании аннотации [`@ManagedBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html), при использовании элемента аннотации `eager = true`. В противном случае эффекта от такого использования элемента не будет никакого.

В момент создания бина обращение из программы происходит, как указывает ошибка, либо в тот момент, когда фреймворк JSF еще не успел создать текущий `FacesContext`, тогда `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` возвращает `null`, либо в тот момент, когда дерево вида еще не инициализировано, т.е. до вызова JSF метода `ViewHandler#createView()`, тогда `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot()` возвращает `null`. Далее мы имеем вызов метода на нулевой ссылке и приведенную ошибку.

Как вы уже поняли, полагаться на `FacesContext` в инициализаторе класса, в принципе, не совсем правильно. Для данного случая я бы рекомендовал установку локали по умолчанию вручную, используя `new Locale("...")`, либо из определенного места в настройках/базе данных/на диске и т.д. в методе `@PostConstruct`.

Answer (score 0):

Если JSF не создает FacesContext, замените:

```
Locale currentLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
```

на вызов определенной локали (например ru):

```
Locale currentLocale = new Locale("ru");
```